# Method of characteristics - inhomogeneous pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, characteristics

The boundary conditions problem:

$2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-14\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=3(x+y)$

Where the boundary conditions are:

$u(x,-6x)=Cos((2x)^2) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

How would this be solved by method of characteristics?

My own attempt:

$a=2,b=-14,c=3(x+y)$

use that:

$\frac{dx}{ds}=a, \frac{dy}{ds}=b,\frac{du}{ds}=c \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{du}{c}=ds$

$\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-14}=\frac{du}{3(x+y)}=ds$

$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{2}{-14}$

$2dy=-14dx \Rightarrow \int2dy=\int-14dx \Rightarrow 2y=-14x+A$

$\Rightarrow A=2y+14x$

Then i've tried to isolate dx and dy and said dx-dy but that didn't go anywhere productive for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{-14}=\frac{du}{3(x+y)}\rightarrow \int-14du = \int3x+3ydy$ is false because you forget $dy$ in $ \int3x+3ydy$ which should be  $\int 3x\,dy+\int 3ydy$ .You cannot integrate $ \int3x\,dy$ because $x$ isn't constant wrt $y$.

Comment: Ah, it should be $\int 3xdy = 3xy$, right?

Comment: No. $\int 3xdy=3xy$ is false because $x$ is not constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-14\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=3(x+y)$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-14}=\frac{du}{3(x+y)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-14}$ :
$$14x+2y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{7x\,dx-y\,dy}{14}=\frac{du}{3}$ because :

$\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-14}=\frac{7x\,dx-y_,dy}{14x+14y}=\frac{du}{3(x+y)}$
$$u-\frac{3}{28}(7x^2-y^2)=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{3}{28}(7x^2-y^2)+F(14x+2y)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

I suppose that you can determine the function $F$ accordingly to the given condition.

Comment: Is that a , on the y?

Comment: Cannot understand your question.

Comment: On y's in the second characteristic eq, there's a little , on the y. $7xdx-y,dy$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-14}=\frac{du}{3(x+y)}=\frac{7xdx-ydy}{14x+14y}$? I can see how this is true.

Comment: In the second characteristic equation : $u-\frac{3}{28}(7x^2-y^2)=c_2$ I cannot see any little a. The equality $\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-14}=\frac{7x\,dx-y_,dy}{14x+14y}$ is simply the application of a well-known elementary property of the fractions :  If $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$ then : $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C}{c_1B+c_2D}$$ with arbitrary parameters $c_1$ and $c_2$ (not both nuls). In the present case we have : $A=dx \:;\: B=2 \:;\: C=dy \:;\: D=-14\:;\: c_1=7x \:;\: c_2=-y$. Nothing mysterious nor complicated !

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense now.
Sorry, its not an a, but the [,] comma on the y's. $y_,$

Comment: The comma is a typo. Now fixed. Thanks you for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

Solve
$$2u_x-14y_y=3(x+y),\quad (1)$$
$$u(x,-6x)=\cos^22x\qquad (2)$$
Steps of solution:

**1 step:**

General solution of
$$2u_x-14y_y=0$$
is $$u=F(7x+y)$$
**2 step:**

Particular solution of (1)
is $$u=6x^2+\frac32xy$$

**3 step:**

Then general solution of (1) is
$$u=6x^2+\frac32xy+F(7x+y)$$

**4 step:**

From (2) if $y=-6x$ we get
$$F(x)=\cos^22x+3x^2$$

**5 step:**

Then solution of initial value problem (1), (2) is
$$u=6x^2+\frac32xy+\cos^2(14x+2y)+3(7x+y)^2\\
=\cos^2(14x+2y)+153x^2+\frac{87}{2}xy+3y^2
$$